# How to structure Oracle in OraClient11g_home1 connection string with host, service-name and port

Tags: oracle, connection-string

In Oracle, I have a 32-bit driver to connect in my 32-bit ODBC `Oracle in OraClient11g_home1`.

I want to connect using host, port, service-name, uid, pwd (as I do in Oracle SQL Developer). But the only versions of connection string that I can find use TNSNames.ora, which I can't modify.

For example I found this connection string:
`Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Dbq=myTNSServiceName;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`

But dbq here is a TNS name. How can I modify this connection string to include host, port, and service-name?

Edit:

I also tried this:

```
"Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;"
```

But I got an error:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 12560, message [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

Comment: If you can't modify the system `tnsnames.ora` file, can you copy that or create your own, and change TNS_ADMIN to its location? Or do you mean you don't know how to modify it?

Comment: I can't do this due to admin issues. Also the tnsnames file is used for other databases so I don't want to change the admin file location. I'm just trying to build the connection string to use in R and Python.

Comment: connect from what client software? SQLPlus, some programing language? https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: I'm connecting from R using ```RODBC``` library with ```odbcDriverConnect``` function. It takes connection string as input. I can connect using Oracle SQL Developer using host/service-name but need to figure out how to modify connection string with that info.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I saw that before, I tried it also. Edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
'DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};DBQ=x.x.x.x:MyPort/MySID;UID=username;PWD=password'
```

Comment: Problem is I no longer have access and can't test, but I will mark this as correct although I can't test it! Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

First SQL Developer connect via JDBC not ODBC.
Are you using SID or service name to connect?
DB Version? Os?
You are using an old terrible (32bit) and unsupported version anymore as far as i know full of bugs.
Try to think about it but in any case try to replace SERVER= with CONNECTSTRING= or SERVICE_NAME with SID